# node js function called from a JavaScript code

Tags: node.js

So I have a node js code that updates and modifies a file content but I would like the data being inserted to come from a JavaScript code. How do I connect the two? Basically how do I have a function in node js that can be called from JavaScript?

Comment: It depends on the architecture or technologies you are currently using but I think a good approach would be creating a Rest API Endpoint with Express. Maybe a POST and send the javascript data as payload, then in your nodejs code handling the data to update/modify the file .

Answer (score 0):

Considering there's not much information to go off in the question, I am going to make a the assumption that you're trying to pass information from JS in a web browser to a node application.

The easiest and best documented way to do this would be to set up a simple web server using a package like [expressJS](https://expressjs.com/) and send data as a POST request using the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) command in the browser.

1. Install express on the node application using the [getting started guide](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html)
2. Write a http path where you can process the data
3. Start the node app
4. Make a call to the path we just created

Example backend code:

```js
const express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(bodyParser);

app.post('/mypath', (req, res) => {
    const myInputData = req.body.data;

    //Do whatever you want with the data

})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Example front-end code:

```js
var data = new FormData();
data.append('data', YOUR_DATA_VAR_HERE)
var options = {
    method: 'POST', 
    body: data
}
fetch('http://localhost:3000/mypath',options)
    .then(function(response){ console.log("Data was sent successfully") })
    .catch(function(error) { console.log("There was an error sending data") })
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but am getting this error: ``` body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5
express deprecated req.host: Use req.hostname instead node_modules\body-parser\index.js:100:29
body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option node_modules\body-parser\index.js:105:29 ```